# Connection refused CakePhp and OVH

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am currently attempting to get CakePHP running on OVH. I uploaded my project but the browser shows that error message:

Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in ../config/bootstrap.php on line 38

Please could anyone give me a hint !

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp 3.0 not running without intl extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746819/cakephp-3-0-not-running-without-intl-extension)

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakephp 3.0 install with composer is broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542187/cakephp-3-0-install-with-composer-is-broken)